# Cost function to output reliable error probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, softmax

I'm using softmax regression but my goal is not to increase the 'accuracy' but instead to create probabilities which are accurate. Using cross entropy or the means squared error (which I'm aware I'm not meant to use but for my purpose works better) both increase the accuracy but the probabilities reduced feel a bit random.

Is there a cost function I could use where the focus is on the probabilities produced? eg when the model says 10000 examples will have a 0.3 probability, I would want 3000 of them to end up being the correct class.

I'm not sure if I am wording this correctly.